# Magento 2 : How to get request and send response in custom REST API?

Tags: magento2, api, response, request

I have created a custom API i need to know how can i get request and response using this custom API ? 
I use this link to create custom API : http://inchoo.net/magento/api-magento/magento-2-custom-api/

Comment: you want to parse the response ?

Comment: yes @ankit Jaiswal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Example : Response 
JSON Output:**

```
{
    "Cancelled": false,
    "MessageID": "402f481b-c420-481f-b129-7b2d8ce7cf0a",
    "Queued": false,
    "SMSError": 2,
    "SMSIncomingMessages": null,
    "Sent": false,
    "SentDateTime": "/Date(-62135578800000-0500)/"
}
```

**If your $result variable is a string json like, you must use json_decode function to parse it as an object or array:
OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [Cancelled] => 
    [MessageID] => 402f481b-c420-481f-b129-7b2d8ce7cf0a
    [Queued] => 
    [SMSError] => 2
    [SMSIncomingMessages] => 
    [Sent] => 
    [SentDateTime] => /Date(-62135578800000-0500)/
)
OUTPUT

Array
(
    [Cancelled] => 
    [MessageID] => 402f481b-c420-481f-b129-7b2d8ce7cf0a
    [Queued] => 
    [SMSError] => 2
    [SMSIncomingMessages] => 
    [Sent] => 
    [SentDateTime] => /Date(-62135578800000-0500)/
)
```

**Now you can work with `$json` variable as an array:**

```
echo $json['MessageID'];
echo $json['SMSError'];
```

// other stuff

=======================

Find the Below Example

Here I have created example for get product by SKU using **magento 2 rest api**. Here is list of API that supported by magento 2.

**Magento 2 REST API Authentication**

```
//Authentication rest API magento2.Please change url accordingly your url
$adminUrl='http://127.0.0.1/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => "wsuser", "password" => "password123");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                       
$ch = curl_init($adminUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);       
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$token=  json_decode($token);
```

======================

Get Product By SKU REST API Magento 2

//Use above token into header

```
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $token"); 

$requestUrl='http://127.0.0.1/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/products/24-MB01';
```

//Please note 24-MB01 is sku

```
$ch = curl_init();
$ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result=  json_decode($result);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Hello @Ankit  I have no idea what should i do from this. Can you please explain more about this ? It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: See I updated Answer with example

Comment: Ok Ankit just one thing where should i need to add this code ?

Comment: if you want to test the code you have to create one php script file on magento2 root folder & add the below code then  Above code provided by me as asample code like that you can test                                                <?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__.'/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$appState = $obj->get("Magento\Framework\App\State");
$appState->setAreaCode("developer");

Comment: check now i updated

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string . It giving error now

Comment: Show your complete code in your question

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake i didnt insert my username password now its working

Comment: Great .............:)

Comment: You are great Ankit. Just because of you i have little knowledge how to work with API's in Magento. Thank you

Comment: Its my pleasure dude :)

Comment: Ankit how to get the request body in the custom rest api endpoint?